# $this:eq(2) is not working in a plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a structure similar to

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="panel">   </div>
    <div class="panel">   </div>
        :
</div>
```

I created a plugin to align the panel under each other.  The panel that I want to see has an opacity of 1 and the others an opacity of 0.

A public function has been created to allow the selection of another panel to have an opacity of 1.

The plugin looks like:

```
(functon($) {
   var someGlobalVars;
   $.fn.panel = function(options} {
      // some logic
      $(this).each(function(index) {
         $(this).css({...});
      )};

   // public function
   $.fn.panel.transition = function(panelNum) {
      $('.wrapper .panel:eq(' + panelNum + ')').css({...}); // <-- works
   };        
});
```

The plugin is called as:

```
$('wrapper .panel').panel();
$('wrapper .panel').panel.transition(2);
```

The plugin is working, but I NEED to remove the class names from the public function by using a this.  I tried difference ways such as:

```
var $myThis = $(this);
$myThis:eq(' + panelNum + ').css({...});
```

BUT NOTHING I try is working.

Can someone please provide a suggestion that I could try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the suggestion worked.  Since $(this) is an array of objects, I tried just using an array index and it worked.

Below are the code changes that I made

```
(functon($) {
   var someGlobalVars;
   var myThis;                    // <-- added
   $.fn.panel = function(options} {
      // some logic
      myThis = $(this);           // <-- added
      $(this).each(function(index) {
         $(this).css({...});
      )};

   // public function
   $.fn.panel.transition = function(panelNum) {
      // $('.wrapper .panel:eq(' + panelNum + ')').css({...}); // <-- changed
      $(myThis[panelNum]).css({...});                          // <-- to this
   };        
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason you use `+ panelNum +` the first time is that you are concatenating a string.

So this:

```
$('.wrapper .panel:eq(' + panelNum + ')')
```

becomes:

```
$('.wrapper .panel:eq( 5 )')  // or whatever the number was
```

This is only because you are using a String as the selector. This is not done when you call functions. Instead you simply use the function and variable names.

```
var $myThis = $(this);

$myThis.eq( panelNum ).css({...});
```

It is by design that jQuery offers a "selector string" version, and a similar method version. It is because there are times to use both forms.

The selector string version gives you an immediate result that is the item at an index.

The method version takes a set, and reduces the set to the item at an index. This gives you the same result as the selector string version, but requires the extra step of reducing the initial set.

---

**EDIT:** I should note that when you do `$(this)`, if `this` represents a single DOM element, then it doesn't make sense to use `.eq()`, since there's only one element, at index `0`.

If `this` represents a jQuery object, then you don't need to wrap it with `$()`. You can just do `this.eq( panelNum )`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$myThis.eq(panelNum)` or `$(this).eq(panelNum)` instead: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 0):

```
$myThis:eq(' + panelNum + ')...
```

Is invalid JS syntax...

I think you're probably trying to achieve something like this:

```
$myThis.filter(':eq(' + panelNum + ')')...
```

or

```
$myThis.eq(panelNum)...
```